# VS2015: Error List doesn't get cleared on new build

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build, visual-studio-2015

There are more than one C++ projects in a solution. Lets compile A, which will fail, and will have errors reported in **Error List** view. Now compile B (assume A is dependent on B), which will succeed. But, the errors rendered by compiling A doesn't go away.

Anyone encountered such issue? How to enable clearing the error-list view on each build (the way it is working for years). The **Output** window, however is clean on each new build.

Comment: The only way i know about to clear the error list is to use the command "clean solution". If no better options comes up it might be your best option.

Comment: it's a bug. file a connect and it'll get punted from release to release until 2025 like all the rest...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you have 'Build Only' or 'Build + Intellisense' selected in the combo box? Many of my errors like this actually come from Intellisense (and tend to be bogus).

[image: Image of Combo in Error List]

Answer (score 1):

I currently have a similar problem with VS2015. I have a solution with c++ and c# wpf projects. Clean checkout, full build, no errors in Output but hundreds of errors appear in Error List. It reminds me of problems with earlier versions of VS back than the only fix was to close all open files but this time this is not helping either. In my case deleting the .suo file helped. See this for reference [VS freaks out](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/quick-tip-what-to-do-when-visual-studio-freaks-out-and-everything-is-red/).

(edit) I read that Xamarin could cause the problem but uninstalling it and also uninstalling all the other addons delivered with VS2015 did not fix the problem. After a clean checkout and full build I got all the errors again.

Comment: Had similar issue. All succeeded build, but tons of errors in the error list. I closed VS, deleted the .suo. Started VS and things went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio 2019, simply closing and restarting the application got rid of the warnings.